# Saving a Person or Group field using REST

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Does anyone know how to save a Person field using REST?

I have tried the following and it works:

```
{ 
   "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.SomeListListItem" } , 
   "MyPersonFieldId" : 1
}
```

But this only works if you know the ID.  I don't have that!  How can I get it?  I have the key which is `i.0#w|domain\userName`.

I tried the following and it doesnt work either:

```
{ 
   "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.SomeListListItem" } , 
   "MyPersonField" : { "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem" }, "Name": "i.0#w|domain\userName" }
}
```

Any ideas??  Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution for your problem? I need to do the same thing, and don't have the user id, only the accountname (from the peoplepicker).

Comment: I have the same issue needing to create a new list item and set a person column value but I only have the username. I have no way of knowing the ID.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't done this with a Person field, but I did do something similar with a managed metadata field. I basically had to pass in additional information as an object to create the value in the field.

See if passing in the ID of the user along with the name works. I'm about to try this myself as I have the same need.

```
{
     "MyPersonField": { "Name": "i.0#w|domain\userName", "ID": 1 }
}
```

EDIT: Ok, updating this field is easier than I thought. I was able to perform the update by simply passing in the ID of the user to the Id field:

```
{
     "MyPersonFieldId": 1
}
```

This means the user should already be in the site collection, so if the user doesn't exist the request will fail.

Comment: can put code of it .i was try with same but not work for me it give 400 response error

Comment: Important is to extend the column name with "Id" at the end

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that User information is a lookup field thereby `MyPersonField` does not exist on your SharePoint list if you use an OData endpoint, I really don't know how to save data but same problem happened to me when I tried to read a user.

for example  `{server}/{api}/list/getbytitle('mylist')/items` does not return `MyPersonField` instead return `MyPersonFieldId`.

But if we use:

```
{server}/{api}/list/getbytitle('mylist')/items/?$select=*,MyPersonField/Name&$expand=MyPersonField
```

We are able to work with `MyPersonField` lookup values.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get Current User ID to save user under People and group column. People column name is `Requestor`. But to save user we have to specify column name as `RequestorId`

```
var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId; // To get current user ID
var itemProperties={'Title':vTitle,'RequestorId':userid};
```